# Control JFrame other void?

Tags: java, class, jframe, void

I want to control JFrame from "PART3" any help?
StackOverFlow asking for more info ;) So my idea is in PART3 g.f I know this is wrong so any help

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        SetUp g =new SetUp();
        g.PART2(); 
        g.PART3();       

}}

class SetUp {
    void PART2()throws IOException{
        JFrame f = new JFrame();

        f.setTitle("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //    System.out.println(f);
    }

    void PART3()throws IOException{    
        SetUp g =new SetUp();
       g.f.setSize(128,128);
       g.f.setLocation(10,10);
       g.f.setVisible(true);

       //    System.out.println(g.f);
    }
}
```

So my idea is in PART3 g.f I know this is wrong so any help

Comment: What do you mean by control JFrame?

Answer (score 1):

`f` needs to be field in order to access it in another method.

```
class SetUp {

    private JFrame f; // `f` is now an instance field of the SetUp class

    void PART2()throws IOException {
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setTitle("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    void PART3()throws IOException{
        // SetUp g =new SetUp();
        // you can directly access 'f' here, there's no need to create a new object

        f.setSize(128,128);
        f.setLocation(10,10);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you use f field and create instance of SetUp object inside SetUp class? This is in this case completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Lemonov hehe, I wasn't done editing yet, I simply reused his code.

Comment: Thank you so much that's great :)